# cpp-ethereum-develop cmake error

Tags: cpp-ethereum, bug

I have downloaded "cpp-ethereum-develop" zip file from github and unzipped it.

While executing "cmake eth"

It gives the following error.

Unknown CMake command "eth_simple_add_executable".

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
```

How to clear this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working with the zip. I also tried several times. You need to clone the repository and pull the submodules, e.g.,:

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum
cd cpp-ethereum
git checkout -b develop
git submodule update --init --recursive

mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake .. 
make -j $(nproc)
```

This should work unless you did forget to mention you are not on Linux.

Comment: when i build cmake .., it produces the following error

Comment: CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1402 (message):
  URL_HASH is set to

    SHA256=087640ebcf7fbcfe8e2717a0b9528fff89c52fcf69fa2a18cc2b538008098f97;DOWNLOAD_NO_PROGRESS;True

  but must be ALGO=value where ALGO is

    MD5|SHA1|SHA224|SHA256|SHA384|SHA512

  and value is a hex string.

Comment: please update your question or paste the whole error output somewhere.

Comment: thank you very much. It is answered in http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9454/cpp-ethereum-build-error