# cpp-ethereum build error

Tags: cpp-ethereum, bug

I have cloned the cpp-ethereum in Linux (centOS) from git as follows as suggested in [cpp-ethereum-develop cmake error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9272/cpp-ethereum-develop-cmake-error)

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum 

cd cpp-ethereum

git checkout -b develop

git submodule update --init --recursive

mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..
```

When I run the `cmake` command

```
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1402 (message):

  URL_HASH is set to

    SHA256=087640ebcf7fbcfe8e2717a0b9528fff89c52fcf69fa2a18cc2b538008098f97;DOWNLOAD_NO_PROGRESS;True

  but must be ALGO=value where ALGO is

    MD5|SHA1|SHA224|SHA256|SHA384|SHA512

  and value is a hex string.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1846 (_ep_add_download_command)
  cmake/jsoncpp.cmake:3 (ExternalProject_Add)
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/cpp-ethereum/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How to solve this problem? Even the log file does not have the proper details about the error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the build process was broken with [this](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/commit/55dc40c64c77f78a95ff198a76928b3858a9dbd1) commit. They'll likely fix it soon, but for now you can do

```
cd cpp-ethereum
git checkout 5669c209f4f8dbb7dc3f744e8e2a9c92f1104ca3
```

and then go ahead with the rest of the build process

You can also open an issue [here](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/issues) to bring this to the developer's attention. Please include detailed specs for your machine (OS version, any error logs, etc.)

Comment: It works fine. However now, I am facing the problem in Json. Error is Could NOT find jsoncpp (missing:  JSONCPP_LIBRARY JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- JsonCpp headers: JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- JsonCpp lib   : JSONCPP_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND