# cpp-ethereum develop json error

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I have cloned the cpp-ethereum in Linux (centOS) from git as follows as suggested in [cpp-ethereum-develop cmake error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9272/cpp-ethereum-develop-cmake-error)

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum 

cd cpp-ethereum

git checkout 5669c209f4f8dbb7dc3f744e8e2a9c92f1104ca3

git checkout -b develop

git submodule update --init --recursive

mkdir -p build
cd build

git clone https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp

cmake ..
```

When building, I get:

```
-- Could NOT find jsoncpp (missing:  JSONCPP_LIBRARY JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIR) 

-- JsonCpp headers: JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND

-- JsonCpp lib   : JSONCPP_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND


CMake Error at cmake/UseJsoncpp.cmake:8 (message):

  Jsoncpp library not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):

  cmake/EthDependencies.cmake:203 (eth_apply)

  cmake/UseJsonRpc.cmake:3 (eth_use)

  cmake/EthDependencies.cmake:203 (eth_apply)

  eth/CMakeLists.txt:7 (eth_use)
```

Is the above problem from path setting or some thing else?

Comment: please share the procedure you followed to install the ethereum cpp and which option did you use

Answer (score 1):

you need to install JSON-RPC (remote procedure call) support for C++ :

https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp

Comment: after installing the above, same error is thrown.

Comment: past the errors in comment and show to commands you used in  the procedure

Comment: above are the errors and procedure I followed.

Comment: you get the same error even after installing the json rpc?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/issues/617

Comment: I have followed the steps and done it in Ubuntu. It is not working in CentOS. cmake is working properly in JSON-RPC-CPP but when i do the cmake in cpp-ethereum then I get the following error

Comment: -- JsonCpp headers: /usr/include/jsoncpp
-- JsonCpp lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so
CMake Error at cmake/Findjson_rpc_cpp.cmake:105 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE needs at least 6 arguments total to
  command.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/UseJsonRpc.cmake:4 (find_package)
  cmake/EthDependencies.cmake:203 (eth_apply)
  eth/CMakeLists.txt:7 (eth_use)